# Apache camel-consuming spring WebFlux functional web rest api from Apache camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-webflux

I have defined a functional web rest api (GET) using spring WebFlux , which is working fine from my WebClientTest

I have apache camel route which has a working route to read file content and send that data to the above rest api like

````
        .routeId("fromFileToRest”)
        .log("consume customer route started")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("GET"))
        .fromRest()
        .to(“http://localhost:8080/customer”).log(“sent consumer data to get api”); ```


But in this camel route, I want to replace hardcoded url in to() with the WebFlux functional api router/handler call, so that when there is a change in uri, this route is not impacted. Could you please suggest how to
````

Answer (score 0):

Possible to add a camel processor in the route which uses HttpClient to invoke downstream with a configurable url in prop file?

Comment: thanks Jacob, but that's next step to calling the api end point. I am looking to replace to(“http://localhost:8080/customer”) with associated Webflux router/handler. Please tell me if there is a way, thanks much